# How do I flush() or ob_flush() response headers while page is still working?

Tags: php, apache, buffer, flush

I need to flush out a header reply immediately while thwe page remains working.

I have the following headers currently (as this is an include all variables are previously defined)

```
<?php 
ob_start();
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must- 
revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
header("Pragma: no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
header("Expires: 0"); // Proxies.
header('HTTP/1.1 201 Created');
header('Location: 
http://'.$ipaddress.':'.$port.'/path/file');
ob_flush();
flush();

...Here there is a Bunch of code that takes a very long time to execute....

?>
```

I have added the following to .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|css)$">
  FileETag None
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header unset ETag
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header set Expires "Wed, 12 Jan 1980 05:00:00 GMT"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Looking on the web I also find reference to (in php.ini)

```
output_buffering
```

I however find few examples . I understand I may be able to but all options in .htaccess ini files. As I understand it I must disable output buffering in BOTH Apache and PHP

Phpinfo says

```
output_buffering    Off
```

When I run wireshark I can see the web server reply takes quite a while before sending a reply.

Also this is XAMPP  PHP 8.0.8 on Windows 10

Any advice?

thanks

Mark